# The server quit without updating PID file

Tags: mysql, database

I tried running optimize on one of my tables, and when I did the server crashed. Now when I try to restart it, I get this error:

> The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/mysql/data/Diskise.pid).

Then when I look at the error log to help me see what happened, I don't really understand it. What can I do to get my server back up?

```
131117 17:13:43 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/mysql/data
2013-11-17 17:13:44 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2013-11-17 17:13:44 29352 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2013-11-17 17:13:44 29352 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2013-11-17 17:13:44 29352 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2013-11-17 17:13:44 29352 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2013-11-17 17:13:44 29352 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2013-11-17 17:13:44 29352 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2013-11-17 17:13:44 29352 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2013-11-17 17:13:44 29352 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2013-11-17 17:13:44 29352 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2013-11-17 17:13:44 29352 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 57196040504
2013-11-17 17:13:44 29352 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2013-11-17 17:13:44 29352 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2013-11-17 17:13:44 29352 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2013-11-17 17:13:44 29352 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
2013-11-17 17:13:44 29352 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 57201283072
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 57204973005
InnoDB: Error: trying to access page number 377945542 in space 0,
InnoDB: space name ./ibdata1,
InnoDB: which is outside the tablespace bounds.
InnoDB: Byte offset 0, len 16384, i/o type 10.
InnoDB: If you get this error at mysqld startup, please check that
InnoDB: your my.cnf matches the ibdata files that you have in the
InnoDB: MySQL server.
2013-11-17 17:13:44 b73ae700  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 3074090752 in file fil0fil.cc line 5423
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
17:13:44 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed, 
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

key_buffer_size=8388608
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=151
thread_count=0
connection_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 67592 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0 thread_stack 0x30000
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x33)[0x84e19b3]
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x3c8)[0x826c218]
[0xb76ef400]
[0xb76ef416]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x4f)[0xb73de1df]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x175)[0xb73e1825]
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld[0x864f06f]
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld[0x861d3f3]
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld[0x861e03d]
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld[0x8605e5c]
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld[0x85d135f]
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld[0x85c649d]
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld[0x85c739e]
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld[0x85c844f]
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld[0x85b33d9]
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld[0x84f593a]
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld(_Z24ha_initialize_handlertonP13st_plugin_int+0x43)[0x81c1c93]
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld[0x82f32bd]
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld(_Z11plugin_initPiPPci+0x7c8)[0x82f5058]
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld(_Z11mysqld_mainiPPc+0x8c3)[0x81bae83]
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld(main+0x1b)[0x819b30b]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf3)[0xb73c94d3]
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld[0x81afa11]
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
131117 17:13:44 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/mysql/data/Diskise.pid ended
```

Comment: Did you check the related questions?

Comment: I have, and none of them have worked.